# Rearrange values in a Pandas DF Cell by some separated value value in alphabetical order

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df:

```
      ID    Foods
0   100 Apple
1   101 Apple | Orange | Grape
2   102 Apples & Peanut Butter | Peanuts | Coffee
3   103 Grapes and Apples | Melon | Butter
4   104 Milk, Cookies | Cake | Cupcake
```

I want to be organize every cell by alphabetical, separated by `|` so the result would be:

```
        ID     Foods
    0   100 Apple
    1   101 Apple | Grape | Orange
    2   102 Apples & Peanut Butter | Coffee | Peanuts
    3   103 Butter | Grapes and Apples | Melon
    4   104 Cake | Cupcake | Milk, Cookies
```

Sample df:

```
df = {
 'ID': {0: '100', 1: '101', 2: '102', 3: '103', 4: '104'},
 'Foods': {0: 'Apple',
  1: 'Apple | Orange | Grape',
  2: 'Apples & Peanut Butter | Peanuts | Coffee ',
  3: 'Grapes and Apples | Melon | Butter',
  4: 'Milk, Cookies | Cake | Cupcake'}}

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.str.split` to split by `|` (+ and whitespace, left or right), call `sorted` (which returns a new sorted list) on each split list, then join them back together:

```
df['Foods'] = df['Foods'].str.split('\s*\|\s*').apply(sorted).str.join(' | ')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    ID                                       Foods
0  100                                       Apple
1  101                      Apple | Grape | Orange
2  102  Apples & Peanut Butter | Coffee  | Peanuts
3  103          Butter | Grapes and Apples | Melon
4  104              Cake | Cupcake | Milk, Cookies
```

Answer (score -1):

Split the foods columns into a list

```
df['Foods'] = df.Foods.str.split('\s*|\s*')
```

Explode the list, sort the values and bring it back to the old format

```
df
.explode('Foods')
.sort_values(by=['Foods'], ascending=True)
.groupby('ID')
.agg(' | '.join)
```